# Flip Right UIView1 to UIView2

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, flip

I have two `UIViews` VW1 and VW2 in the same `UIViewController`.
I'm trying to flip to the right from VW1 to VW2 and using the following code that I don't know how and where to call the method?

```
-(void)FlipFromRight
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:uiView2  cache:YES];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Above code is not working for me.

Comment: I want to do the flip between views when swiping from right to left on the screen.I also tried to use a swipe gesture between the views and it's not working, it's working only for different ViewControllers

Comment: try to hide and show only one view in above method.. define condition on the method and show view1 if its hidden otherwise show view2 ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to do :

```
if ([VW1 superview])
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];  
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:aTableBGView cache:NO];

        [VW1 removeFromSuperview];
        [mainView addSubview:VW2];
        [mainView sendSubviewToBack:VW1];
    }
    else
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];  
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:aTableBGView cache:NO];

        [[mainView viewWithTag:2001] removeFromSuperview]; // VW2's tag ID
            [mainView addSubview: VW1];
        [mainView sendSubviewToBack: VW2];
    }   
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

here add one uIButton like name "btnSwipe" on navigationbar or on the MainViewcontroller and after that just give the button title for example i.e "Left".
after that give the action event with this bellow method

```
-(IBAction)FlipFromRight:(id)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    if ([btnSwipe.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Left"])
   {
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:uiView1  cache:YES];
[btnDraw setTitle:@"Right" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }
else{
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:uiView2  cache:YES];
[btnDraw setTitle:@"Left" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

here just give the IBAction from xib to btnSwipe and it will work

i hope this is useful to you..

:)